# Error testing styles of React component with Jest

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, jestjs

I have a file style.scss that holds styling for my TimeBlock component below. I wrote a unit test (using Jest) to check the styling of the component, but it fails. However, if I use inline styling for the TimeBlock component instead of importing style.scss, the test passes. Why isn't the styling being applied in my test when it's imported from a separate file?

TimeBlock.jsx...

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.scss';

const TimeBlock = ({id, activeState, onClick}) => {
    return (
        <div data-testid={id} onClick={onClick} className={`time-block ${activeState}`}/>
    )

}

export default TimeBlock;
```

style.scss...

```
.time-block {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #258381;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 64px;
    height: 24px;
}
```

In TimeBlock.test.js...

```
import React from 'react';
import TimeBlock from './TimeBlock';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { screen } from '@testing-library/dom'

test('block is white', () => {
    const handleClick = jest.fn();

    render(<TimeBlock id={1} activeState={''} onClick={handleClick}/>);

    expect(screen.getByTestId('1')).toHaveStyle('background: #FFFFFF')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've came accross with github issues and limitations about `rtl` and `jsdom` in regards of `.toHaveStyle()`.

It appears that the only way to do it is to pass it in as an inline style, as the problem is recognizing external stylesheets:

```
<div 
  style={{background: '#FFFFFF'}} 
  data-testid={id} onClick={onClick} 
  className={`time-block ${activeState}`}
/>
```

Having said the above, **it's really not recommended to bend the code for the sake of passing a test**, but I am sure you agree with this, perhaps another tool is what you need, [maybe Cypress's way of CSS testing](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/assertions.html#CSS) but careful cause it can easily become cumbersome, otherwise it's great just for a few elements.